# Function call inside the throttle isn't getting triggered javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, throttling

I have a method `onMouseWheel()` which gets triggered on mousewheel/trackpad scroll. In this method, I normalize the `delta` and pass the mouse coordinates to a function `zoom()` which handles the zoom.

With the trackpad, when I do a quick swipe up gesture, the `onMouseWheel()` gets triggered `n` times (here `n > 1`), computing the `delta` `n` times and calling the `zoom()` method `n` times.

I tried to solve this problem by using `throttle()`. But the function call never gets triggered inside the `throttle()`. Am I doing something wrong here, could any one point me in the right direction.

Here is the following code: [The mouse event is handled by angular's host listener]

```
// Example from [link][1]
const throttle = (func, limit) => {
    let lastFunc
    let lastRan
    return function () {
        const context = this
        const args = arguments
        if (!lastRan) {
            func.apply(context, args)
            lastRan = Date.now()
        } else {
            clearTimeout(lastFunc)
            lastFunc = setTimeout(function () {
                if ((Date.now() - lastRan) >= limit) {
                    func.apply(context, args)
                    lastRan = Date.now()
                }
            }, limit - (Date.now() - lastRan))
        }
    }
}

@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event'])
onMouseWheel(evt: MouseWheelEvent) {
        let delta = 0;
        let factor: number;
        evt.preventDefault();
        delta = (evt.detail < 0 || evt.deltaY < 0) ? 1 : (evt.wheelDelta > 0) ? 1 : -1; // Used example from http://phrogz.net/js/wheeldelta.html
        let offset = $(this.root).offset();
        let mX = evt.pageX - offset.left;
        let mY = evt.pageY - offset.top;
        if (!disabled) {
            throttle(() => {this.service.zoom(mX, mY, delta);}, 100);
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to call `throttle` to *make a throttled function*, which you then can call. Calling `throttle` itself in rapid succession won't help.

Comment: I just edited it. I clicked on submit accidentally.

Comment: You are right @Bergi Thank you for your help.